# How to get and manage a second or multiple Twitter accounts?

Tags: twitter

What is the official Twitter policy or tools for managing multiple accounts?

I need to tweet in two different languages, and I have decided that the best way to do that is with different accounts. What's the Twitter policy for this? Do they support this and is there a way to manage multiple accounts within one browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support to allow you to sign in via a single browser into two Twitter accounts.

As soon as you navigate to twitter.com you should see that you are already logged into the account you most recently logged in to (assuming you didn't sign out).

The solution would be to use an application. There are many desktop and mobile applications that support multiple accounts.

To achieve this via web browsers you would need to make use of two browsers in your operating system.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid off.  It's cumbersome; I don't mind using an app but it would be easier to do everything from one browser.

Comment: No matter what I do now days, I can't get away with using less than 2 browsers, and it's far more common that I'm using 4 or 5.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can just go incognito for one of the windows allowing two users on the same browser.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Twitter client like [TweetDeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) or [Socialite](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/socialite/) to manage multiple accounts. There are a couple of applications to let you use multiple Gmail accounts on the same browser. There must be something for Twitter too. It's just how they store the cookies on your browser.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official support from Twitter, you'll have to use a third-party application or web app.

I've been using [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com) with great success.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to phwd's answer, numerous browsers allow an "incognito" mode these days.  I believe that IE8 is included in the list.

That should work in this situation.